# How do I get my navigation bar to go across the entire page? Right now its in the top right corner

Tags: html, css

I was trying to follow a tutorial since this is my first project and somewhere along the way, I messed up. I'm trying to make it so the navbar goes across the top of the page, right now its nested in the top right, and the hover elements don't work on it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <link href= "newstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <nav>
            <a href="" class="logo">Kashvi</a>
         <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="left-sidebar"> </div>
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="left-col">
            <img src="background.jpg">
           </div>
        <div class="right-col">
            <h1>Welcome!</h1>   
            <p>
                For now, this website will host my thoughts on subjects close to me. It's basically my journal. Have a look around!
            </p>

            <div class="blogs">
                <div class="icon">
                    <h3>Blogs</h3>
                        <a href=" "></a>
            </div>
            <div class="aboutme">
                <div class="icon">
                    <h3>About Me</h3>
                        <a href=" "></a>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my stylesheet: I think I confused myself on some attributes which is why I'm stuck

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
.header{
    min-height:100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background:rgb(176, 175, 243);
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
nav{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 16px;
}   
.navbar{
    text-align: center;
    background-color:rgb(129, 128, 199);
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 18px;
}
.navbar ul li{
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 1em;
    margin: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.navbar ul li a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.navbar ul li a:hover{
    background-color:rgb(116, 115, 180);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    position: static;
}
.navbar ul li::after{
    width: 100%;
    height:3px;
    background-color: #964800;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:1;
    transition: 0.5s;
    content: '',  
}
.left-sidebar{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgb(129, 128, 199);
}
.row{
    padding:0 10%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
.left-col{
    flex-basis:40%;
}
.right-col{
    flex-basis:55%;
}
.left-col img{
    width: 80%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.right-col h1{
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight:600;
}
.right-col p{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 20px 0 70 px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.blogs{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.icon{
    width:103px;
    height:40px;
    background:#fff;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius:6px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.icon h3{
    font-weight: none;
    color:black;
    z-index: 1;
}
.icon a{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgb(230, 230, 230);
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    opacity:0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Right now you are missing several closing div tags... I suggest going through your HTML doc with a keen eye and looking closely at where you need to properly close your div tags. If a tag is not closed and missing the browser will close it automatically, if the browser is closing these divs where you did not intend for them to be closed, it could cause unwanted issues with your layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your trying to keep the menu (`.navbar`) on the right side or do you want it centered in the page?

Depending on what you want, you need to either add a background-color to your `nav` or you want to add `width: 100%` to your `.navbar` class.

As for your issue with your nav list-items moving when you hover... you probably want to add the `padding: 10px 25px` to non-hover state and remove it from the hover state. As is, when you hover, it is making the list-item bigger, which then shifts the other list-items. Better to have the padding on before the hover so that you don't add padding during hover. Unless you like that effect, of course.